# Как исправить ошибку при php artisan db:seed?

Tags: laravel

Как исправить ошибку при php artisan db:seed?

```
php artisan db:seed
Seeding: UsersTableSeeder
Seeding: BlogCategoriesTableSeeder

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'kategoriya10' for key 'blog_categories_slug_unique' (SQL: insert into `blog_categories` (`title`, `slug`, `parent_id`) values (Категория10, kategoriya10, 0))

  at /var/www/php.xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'kategoriya10' for key 'blog_categories_slug_unique'")
      /var/www/php.xxx/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:123

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'kategoriya10' for key 'blog_categories_slug_unique'")
      /var/www/php.xxx/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:121

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

2020_01_03_054102_create_blog_categories_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class BlogCategoriesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $categories = [];

        $cName = 'Без категории';
        $categories = [
            'title' => $cName,
            'slug' => str_slug($cName),
            'parent_id' => 0,
        ];

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            $cName = 'Категория' . $i;
            $parenId = ($i > 4) ? rand(1, 4) : 1;
            $categories = [
                'title' => $cName,
                'slug' => str_slug($cName),
                'parent_id' => 0,
            ];
        }

        \DB::table('blog_categories')->insert($categories);
    }
}
```

2020_01_03_054729_create_blog_posrs_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBlogPosrsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blog_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('title');

            $table->text('excerpt')->nullable();

            $table->text('content_raw');
            $table->text('content_html');

            $table->boolean('is_published')->default(false);
            $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('blog_categories');

            $table->index('is_published');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('blog_posrs');
    }
}
```

BlogCategoriesTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class BlogCategoriesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $categories = [];

        $cName = 'Без категории';
        $categories = [
            'title' => $cName,
            'slug' => str_slug($cName),
            'parent_id' => 0,
        ];

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            $cName = 'Категория' . $i;
            $parenId = ($i > 4) ? rand(1, 4) : 1;
            $categories = [
                'title' => $cName,
                'slug' => str_slug($cName),
                'parent_id' => 0,
            ];
        }

        \DB::table('blog_categories')->insert($categories);
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
         $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
         $this->call(BlogCategoriesTableSeeder::class);
         factory(\App\Models\BlogPost::class, 100)->create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код из BlogCategoriesTableSeeder всегда будет генерировать одни и те же данные:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Категория10
    [slug] => Категория10
    [parent_id] => 0
)
```

И так как в таблице blog_categories на поле slug установлен уникальный ключ. При вставке вы получаете ошибку о том, что такое значение уже есть в бд.

Варианты решения:

1. Скорректируйте BlogCategoriesTableSeeder чтобы он всегда генерировал уникальные данные.  Например так:

```
        $categories = [];
        $cName = 'Без категории'.rand();
        $categories[] = [
            'title' => $cName,
            'slug' => $cName,
            'parent_id' => 0,
        ];

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            $cName = 'Категория' . rand();
            $parenId = ($i > 4) ? rand(1, 4) : 1;
            $categories[] = [
                'title' => $cName,
                'slug' => $cName,
                'parent_id' => $parenId,
            ];
        }
```

2. Уберите в таблице blog_categories уникальный ключ.